# Why did J&J go for one dose?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination

The latest news from the US is that the CDC & FDA [recommend](https://www.cdc.gov/media/releases/2021/p1021-covid-booster.html) a booster shot after only two months following the "single dose" J&J vaccine.

Given the Fauci [comment](https://www.businessinsider.com/fauci-jj-vaccine-should-have-been-a-two-dose-vaccine-2021-10) that J&J "should have been a two-dose vaccine to begin with", I looked through the initial preclinical data of J&J and sure enough there's [this](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.11.17.368258v2.full):

> [image]

Spreading the same total vaccine amount two doses improved titers in macaques. So, do we know anything why J&J went for the "single dose" thing? I mean is there any later clinical data in which there wasn't much difference between one two doses of J&J?

Comment: Possibly more of a strategic business decision? They knew what Moderna and Pfizer were doing, so being the only one with a single-dose option would be attractive to a lot of customers.

Answer (score 2):

According to a March 2021 report quoting an infectious disease expert from the University of California San Francisco, Dr. Monica Ghandi, the J&J (Janssen) vaccine was proposed as a one-dose vaccine because:

> “After one dose, across all populations, even in older people, the
> antibody response and T-cell response were excellent and increased
> over time.”

https://www.ucsf.edu/news/2021/03/420071/how-effective-johnson-johnson-covid-19-vaccine-heres-what-you-should-know

In the same article, Dr. Ghandi also pointed out that an advantage of a one-dose vaccine is that:

> “on a population level, the availability of a one-dose vaccine can
> really speed up vaccinations and help bring total cases down.”

In a January 2021 commentary in Nature, an  infectious disease expert at the Medical University of South Carolina, Dr. Krutika Kuppalli, described some logistical advantages of a single dose vaccine in certain populations as follows:

> “And bringing vaccine recipients back for their second dose can be a
> logistical challenge, particularly with people who are homeless, who
> use drugs or who live in rural areas”

https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-00119-7

A February 2021 CNN report quotes a spokesperson for J&J quoting the World Health Organization as follows:

> "A one-dose vaccine is considered by the World Health Organization to
> be the best option in pandemic settings, enhancing access,
> distribution and compliance."

https://www.cnn.com/2021/02/23/health/johnson--johnson-covid-19-vaccine-fda-committee/index.html

Thus, J&J might have had a business motivation for making a one-dose vaccine looking at the anticipated world market, although this is speculative.